# Kendo UI grid initialized from table -- how to validate?

Tags: javascript, validation, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am testing out the Kendo UI grid and am having a little difficulty finding a way to validate my updates through the API when I am initializing the grid from an existing table. 
All CRUD works as expected, I just can't validate on the client side before it is submitted.

Is there a built in way to do my validation given this scenario? 
(the data here is completely arbitrary)

A finger point in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

My javascript:

```
    $('table.data-table').kendoGrid(
    {
        toolbar: ["create"],
        editable: 'popup',
        sortable: true,
        pageable: { pageSize: 10, pageSizes: true },
        filterable: true,
        columnMenu: true,
        columns: [
            { field: "ID", title: "ID" },
            { field: "name", title: "Name" },
            { field: "capital", title: "Capital City" },
            { field: "largest_city", title: "Largest City" },
            { field: "population", title: "Population" },
            { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: '&nbsp;' }
        ],
        save: myUpdateFunction,
        remove: myRemoveFunction
    });
```

My html:

```
<table class="data-table">    
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Capital</th>
                <th>Largest City</th>
                <th>Population</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>        
        <tr>
            <td>AK</td>
            <td>ALASKA</td>
            <td>Juneau</td>
            <td>Anchorage</td>
            <td>698473</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
         ....
         </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it turns out this is pretty easy. By customizing the editor template you can add the required attribute. So in the columns add a function name to the editor property

```
    columns: [
        { field: "ID", title: "ID", editor: requiredField },
        { field: "name", title: "Name", editor: requiredField },
        { field: "capital", title: "Capital City" },
        { field: "largest_city", title: "Largest City" },
        { field: "population", title: "Population" },
        { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: '&nbsp;' }
    ],
```

And inside the function you can format/customize the input as needed. In my case the key is just adding the required attribute.

```
function requiredField(container, options) {
    var theInput = '<input class="k-input k-textbox" name="' + options.field + '" required data-     bind="value: ' + options.field + '" />';
    $(theInput).appendTo(container);
}
```